# Unit testing NServiceBus handler's handling of reply to its send

Tags: testing, nservicebus

I have a handler which, when it handles some event, sends a request and, depending on the reply, might publish an alert. I'm trying to test this using the NServiceBus Testing framework, but can't quite see how to pretend the bus is replying. I've seen examples of how to test send (using Test.Handler(...).ExpectSend...) and how to test reply *in the other handler that is doing the reply* (using Test.Handler(...).ExpectReply), but nothing about stubbing the reply to test the handling of the reply.

Here's what my handler's Handle method looks like:

```
public void Handle(SomeEvent @event)
{
   bus.Send<SomeRequest>(request => { request.Stuff = @event.Stuff })
       .Register<SomeReply>(reply => { if (reply.OhNo) bus.Publish(new SomeAlert("augh!")); });
}
```

And here's what the test looks like so far:

```
Test.Handler(bus => new MyHandler(bus, serviceMock.Object)).
   ExpectSend(verifyRequest).
   // thought maybe something here like .StubReply(someReply) or something?
   ExpectPublish(verifyAlert).
   OnMessage(@event, "xyz");
```

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Message handlers are single call objects with no state, so the call to .Register won't work as you expect. You could move the reply handling logic to a separate message handler (as it doesn't appear like you have any behavior that depends on remembering something from the request) or you could use a saga if you need a more involved orchestration.

Incidentally, you wouldn't use .Register with your sagas either - instead you'd have a separate Handle method for the response. They also have a more complete testing API, though I wouldn't consider that an argument for using them in this case.

Start with a separate handler for your response message type.

Comment: Ok -- I was on the verge of giving up and adding a separate handler. But the Full Duplex example sure makes it look like the Register callback is the 'right' way. Could you explain, then, when .Register is appropriate? BTW, thanks for the fast answer -- you guys always really rock for that!

Comment: .Register is for registering for callback notifications within a web application, when you're trying to force the asynchronous messaging to behave more like an RPC call. It's somewhat of a messaging anti-pattern and I wouldn't ever lean on it too much.